# contract tracing measures

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "contract tracing measures" mean "contact tracing measures" here? Or was the author actually intended to write "contact tracing measures" yet miswrite it as "contract tracing measures"?

> A year into the Coronavirus pandemic, China has effectively controlled the spread of Covid-19 within its borders, putting in place efficient lockdown and **contract tracing measures** and conducting mass testing for the virus for every small outbreak.

> Source: [hindustan times](https://www.hindustantimes.com/world-news/german-expert-denies-saying-covid-origin-not-in-wuhan-as-china-passes-the-buck/story-C97H1gRVT4VjBQ4CwLGTAK.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly a *typographical error*, or *typo*.  "Contact tracing" is the appropriate phrase for this context.

("Contract tracing" would be a bureaucratic process of researching written contracts to determine who owns something.  This is *completely irrelevant* to the topic of COVID-19.)